# How to prevent "polluting" variables in a Jest test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My test looks like this:

```
const aframeViewer = new VRMaker.AframeViewer()
let el
let panoramas
let panorama

beforeEach(() => {
  panorama = { objectId: '1' }
  panoramas = [panorama]
  el = 'vrmaker-aframe'
})

describe('commonViewer', () => {

  it('addPanoramas', () => {
    const oldPanoramas = clone(panoramas)
    aframeViewer.addPanoramas([{ objectId: '2' }])
    expect(aframeViewer.getPanoramas()).not.toBe(oldPanoramas)
  })

  it('getPanoramas', () => {
    expect(aframeViewer.getPanoramas()).toBe(panoramas)
  })

  it('getCurrentPanorama', () => {
    expect(aframeViewer.getCurrentPanorama()).toBe(panorama)
  })
})
```

The problem here is that `aframeViewer.addPanoramas([{ objectId: '2' }])` turns this:

```
[{ objectId: 1 }]
```

Into this

```
[{ objectId: 1 }, { objectId: '2' }]
```

Therefore the `getPanoramas` test has a polluted variable. (`getCurrentPanorama` suffers from the same problem.)

What's the best way to avoid these kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare `let aframeViewer;` and in the `beforeEach` add:

   `aframeViewer = new VRMaker.AframeViewer()`
2. Don't count on one test to run before another test, make sure to do whatever you need to do either in `beforeEach` or at the beginning of the test.

Comment: Thanks! You're working ta Netflix? Can I have your autograph?

Comment: @alex lol, I'm working for a small startup now, please cross your fingers for me! :)